# How do I remove empty space in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a login xml which is built with ConstraintLayout.There are empty spaces appear top of the layout when I remove the login edit text.I've tried change to Vertical bias but it doesn't change.Also, I tried to move every object to guidline1 but nothing change. This is the screen to what it looks like.
[image: Screen]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbgs"
    tools:context=".login">



    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1.0"/>
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="-480dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cubuk" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cubuk2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="-380dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cubuk2" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cubuk3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-690dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cubuk3" />



    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/consraintLayoutLoginView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineBottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineRight"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineLeft"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineTop"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLoginView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLoginView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLoginView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLoginView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLoginView45"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineLoginView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baslatext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13sp"
            android:text="  Hemen Başla  "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/baslatext"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView2"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/baslatext"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView2"/>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/googlebtn"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineLoginView5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView3" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/dogrular"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/facesbg"
            android:text="Login"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineLoginView5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView3" />



        <View
            android:id="@+id/emailgir"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/emailbtn"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView45"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineLoginView4"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13sp"
            android:text="Google"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.385"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button10"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/button10"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.890"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button10"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/google_circle512" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13sp"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.09"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dogrular" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.890"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dogrular"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook_circle" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13sp"
            android:text="E-posta"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/emailgir"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/emailgir"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.500"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/emailgir" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/emailgir"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/emailgir"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.890"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/emailgir"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/emailgir"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.545"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/email" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So you don't want any space inside the ConstraintLayout which has your buttons, right? If so then you can simply set that ConstraintLayout height to wrap_content.

Comment: But I also want to auto resize for different screen sizes.That's why I don't use the height attribute.

Comment: So these are trade-offs that you will face. Your design might look perfect on one device, but increasing or decreasing screen size will definitely have an impact on the design. You can try to play around with the Guidelines to get a good fit for this device, but changing the screen size might cause the design to get disrupted.